# Unable to return/get response from closure

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, adonis.js, vogels

I want to get the result from the closure function. I did try doing some callback functions too but still I'm getting the same issue. I was able to console.log the result inside the closure/callback but can't return the response into a variable. I tried some of the solutions posted already but weren't able to succeed.

Here's my code:

```
var fcmTokens = [input.fcmToken];
        switch(topicType) {
            case 'post':
                const username = (input.username).toLowerCase();
                const userPrefix = Config.get(`setting.topic.user.prefix`);
                fcmTokens =  Topic.get(`${userPrefix}-${username}`, {AttributesToGet : ['fcmToken']}, function(err,foundTopic) {
                    var result = foundTopic.attrs.fcmToken;
                    console.log(result) //Able to log my expected result
                    return result;
                })

                console.log(fcmTokens) //undefined

            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve my own issue by installing a library called promisified-vogels as my Model is using a DynamoDB.

From my current code above to this:

```
let userTopic =  await Topic
                    .getAsync(`${userPrefix}-${username}`,{ConsistentRead: true, AttributesToGet : ['fcmToken']}) //from original function "get" changed to "getAsync" 
                    .then(function(user){
                        return user.attrs.fcmToken;
                    })
                    .catch(function(err){
                      console.log(err)
                    });
fcmTokens = userTopic;  // i was able to get the list of record im expecting.
```

Reference Library : https://github.com/servel333/vogels-promisified